# Is it possible to create a discord bot with no discord bot tag?

Tags: discord

so I have this question. Is it possible to create a discord bot that can be runned, but doesn't have the [Bot] tag after the name? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* but it's not allowed. All official Discord bots will have the bot tag. It's possible to create a userbot with a user token, and this would not have the bot tag. However, selfbots [go against Discord TOS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-)

Comment: Ah, I am just made aware of this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make code that controls a discord acc. Like you log in and the "bot" can auto type stuff if certain words are detected in the html code.